# How to trigger OAuth2 authentication in Zuul API gateway if a downstream service responds with a 401

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm experimenting with three Spring cloud (boot) applications.

1. An Authentication Server on port 9999
2. A basic backend-sample that has secured and unsecured endpoints on port 9008
3. A basic Zuul API gateway with several routes (secured and unsecured) to the backend-sample on port 9000

The backend-sample boot application is annotated as a resource server (@EnableResourceServer) and secures some endpoints with a ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

When I first call one of the routes that are secured on the Zuul API gateway, I get redirected to the authentication server's login page. After logging in there, I get redirected to the secured route I initially requested. Secured backend-sample endpoints behave as expected which means that the backend-sample does get the granted roles for the supplied token. If I hit a backend-sample endpoint I don't have the proper role for, I get an OAuth 403 response. Everything fine in this case.

We need to put legacy services behind the API gateway as well. These render html and should be able to trigger a login when the user hits a secured area there. We can't secure these areas on API gateway route level as the legacy backends have complicated (grown) permission models for many different sub URLs.

Does anyone know a good way to make a Spring-cloud API gateway redirect to an authentication server's login in such a downstream 401-response case? I tried a simple redirect in a ZuulFilter of type "post" but failed as the response is already committed there.

Backend-sample application.yml;

```html
server:
    port: 9008
    
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

API gateway application.yml:

```yml
server:
    port: 9008
zuul:
   proxy:
      addProxyHeaders: true
   sensitive-headers: 
   routes:
      unsecured-backend-sample:
         path: /unsecured-backend-sample/**
         url: http://localhost:9008
      authorized-backend-sample:
         path: /authorized-backend-sample/**
         url: http://localhost:9008/
      user-role-secured-backend-sample:
         path: /user-role-secured-backend-sample/**
         url: http://localhost:9008/
      xxx-role-secured-backend-sample:
         path: /xxx-role-secured-backend-sample/**
         url: http://localhost:9008/
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

Comment: Did your post filter run before or after SendResponseFilter?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Spencer. I think my initial attempt was after SendResponseFilter where it's too late. I found a ZuulFilter solution and will post it here as an answer. Would be cool if you could comment it. If you like it and think it's compatible with spring-cloud's architectural concepts, I'd love to commit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works great for me. I wrote a ZuulFilter that handles only 401 responses and redirects to login. It also saves the rejected request in an HTTP session request cache so the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler can redirect you back to the initially requested downstream service URL.

```java
@Component
public class LoginOnDownstreamUnauthorizedResponseFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        // Only handle downstream 401s
        return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getResponse().getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = ctx.getResponse();

        // We need to put the rejected request in the request cache for SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        // to find it's way back to the initial request URI after successful authentication.
        requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);

        String text = String.format("Downstream service %s responded with a status code 401.", request.getRequestURI());
        logger.debug(text + " Calling Authentication entry point.");
        try {
            authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, new InsufficientAuthenticationException(text));
        } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to redirect to Authentication entry point", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        // make sure to run before SendResponseFilter
        return 500;
    }

}
```